# Showing two images per line, max of 4

Tags: php

```
$dir = dir("/adunits/");
$file_count = 0;
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        if (!is_dir($curpath.$file)) {
           $files[$file_count] = $file;
        $file_count = $file_count + 1;
        } // not a directory
    } // not . or ..
} // read through dir

$dir->close();
shuffle($files);
echo "<h4 class=\"widgettitle\">Sponsors</h4>";
for ($i = 0; $i <= $file_count-1; $i++) {
        $target = "http://" . str_replace(".jpg", "", $files[$i]);
    if (file_exists("/adunits/$files[$i]")) {
        echo "<center><div class=\"adunit_position\"><a href=\"$target\" target=\"_new\"><img class=\"adunit\" src=\"http://temp.com/adunits/$files[$i]\" alt=\"$files[$i]\" /></a></div></center>";
    }
}
```

I need to modify this to show two images per line and a max of 4 images. Right now the directory has only 4 images but in the near future it will have many more... probably like 100.

I did not write this code and I am trying to learn and grow in my php knowledge.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add your HTML output which you expect.

Comment: mrjamesmyers was able to help below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to Max Images you can create a variable with a default value of 4 e.g `$maxImages = 4;` and then change this value based on the file count and then loop over $maxImages.

I would consider changing the HTML markup a bit to use an Unordered List `<ul><li></li></ul>` and using CSS to limit the amount of images on a line to 2.
In below example (untested) I have used nth-of-type and CSS floats however there may be more modern/better ways of achieving desired result.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/
I have also replaced echo ""; with breaking in and out of PHP which allows for better syntax highlighting.  Also means you don't need to use escape characters to use double quotes.  I would say take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php to learn a bit more about usage of single quote and double quotes.

```
<?php
$dir = dir("/adunits/");
$i = 0;
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        if (!is_dir($curpath.$file)) {
           $files[$i] = $file;
           $i++;
        } // not a directory
    } // not . or ..
} // read through dir

$dir->close();
shuffle($files);

$maxImages = 4;
$file_count = count($files);
if($file_count < 4) {
    $maxImages = $file_count;
}

?>
<h4 class="widgettitle">Sponsors</h4>
    <ul class="adunit_list">
    <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < $maxImages; $i++) {
            $target = "http://" . str_replace(".jpg", "", $files[$i]);
            if (file_exists("/adunits/$files[$i]")) { ?>
                <li class="adunit_position"><a href="<?php echo $target ?>" target="_new"><img class="adunit" src="http://temp.com/adunits/<?php echo $files[$i]?>" alt="<?php echo $files[$i]?>" /></a></li>;
                <?php
            }
        } ?>
    </ul>

<style>
.adunit_list li {
    float: left;
}
.adunit_list li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    clear:  both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a beauty. I did need to modify your code and add a couple echo statements because of where/how the code was being used but besides that it worked perfectly.. thank you so much! Now I will know how to do something similar the next time!

Comment: Sure thing. However, I am not sure if it is the original code that we edited or your added code but it seems that there have to be at least five images in the directory now for anything to show up. I saw this because I changed the code for use in a different place (using a different directory too) to have a maxImages of 1 and the image was not showing up.... until I had two images in the directory. Any ideas?

Comment: At a quick glance could be the <= in the for loop, maybe change to just < because $i starts at 0

Comment: Have updated.  Also refactored so $file_count is populated by counting array rather than increment and subtraction as a bit confusing.  Also used $i for array index and then shorthand increment

Comment: Not quite there... I had to set file_count to check if it is less than 0 to get the images to show up for the section where I duplicated the code to show one image from a different directory. if($file_count < 0) {
    $maxImages = $file_count;
}